# Does ConcurrentHashMap make a copy of itself?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I recently attended an interview where the interviewer asked me question about `HashMap` and `ConcurrentHashMap`. After the initial thread-safety benefits I said that it does not throw `ConcurrentModificationException` when it is being traversed as opposed to `HashMap`.

The interviewer continued and asked me why it does not throw it. I said that internally `HashMap` has a variable `modCount` which keeps the number of modifications done to the map and `Iterator` is comparing this number against the one it's been initialised with at creation. If this number is different it will throw an exception and this comparison does not happen for `ConcurrentHashMap`.

He then said `ConcurrentHashMap` will make a copy of itself when traversing.

I have doubts about this statement since haven't come across this before. Even reading the documentation does not give me a sufficient answer.

Would it make at any point a copy (read or write)?

Comment: *ConcurrentHashMap will make a copy of itself when traversing*--He's wrong. Look at the source code

Comment: `He then said ConcurrentHashMap will make a copy of itself when traversing.` anything not in the javadoc is pure bs. Other implementation details may be true at some point in time, but cannot qualify for such a strong statement.

Comment: I hope you didn't get the job.

Comment: Your interviewer may be thinking of CopyOnWriteArrayList, which does create a copy on any write event.  It also doesn't throw a ConcurrentModificationException, because any changes aren't reflected in the iterator.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it has nothing to do with making a copy of anything. And no throwing `ConcurrentModificationException` isn't necessarily under multi-threading environment.

Several points regarding to your questions.

1. `ConcurrentModificationException` has nothing to do with concurrency (and it actually has a bad name). It's thrown when you are iterating through some data structure and you use the iterator again after making some modification to the structure. This is called `fail fast` behavior. Due to such behavior it can be thrown under multi-threading context but has no dependency to that at all.
2. `ConcurrentHashMap` is a delicated structure and I recommend you to read through it. The way it achieve concurrency is by

   - Any threads accessing different buckets in the map are naturally separated so no need to synchronize between them except for rehashing case.
   - For the threads accessing the same bucket, if the bucket is empty it uses CAS i.e. `AtomicReference` to access the only element in the bucket.
   - In case the bucket under operation has hash collision and has multiple elements, its kept as a linked list (except for the case of JDK 1.8 which reworks the link list into a binary tree to achieve better performance under extreme hash collision). The benefit of a linked list is it supports concurrency naturally as long as you operate on the next pointer in CAS way.

There are still a lot of coding art in the `ConcurrentHashMap` so I suggest you to read its source code thoroughly.